# Php code to match string if any word is in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have been trying to match post query sting if it contain any word in array.
I try to execute sql query using the command to update or select but i don't want to drop or delete row and table.

Please bellow code is not matching the sting in array well

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['QueryCode'])){ 

             $RequestQuey = htmlspecialchars($_POST['QueryCode']);
             $sqlchecker = strtolower($RequestQuey);
             $bads_arrays = array(
             'ALTER', 
             'TABLE', 
             'DROP');

             foreach ($bads_arrays as $strings){
                if (strpos($sqlchecker , $strings) !== false) {
                    echo "Match found"; 
                    return false;
                }else{
            echo "Not found!";
            return true;    
            }
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a strtolower() on the examined string but you have uppercase words in the array. So either replace strpos with stripos or change the words in the array to be lowercase or convert the examined string ($sqlchecker) to uppercase.

```
$anyMatched = false;
foreach ($bads_arrays as $strings){
    if (stripos($sqlchecker , $strings) !== false) {
        $anyMatched = true;
    }
}

echo ($anyMatched ? 'Match found' : 'Not Found');
return $anyMatched;
```

Comment: it worked but still didn't match well when i enter `drop table` it show not found but `drop alter` this show found in case of debug i try to print $strings inside foreach it only contain `alter`

Comment: your code work fine but it have one problem when i type something like this `alterdatatable` it will show `Match found` but in array i add only `alter` so is possible `alterdatatable` this will be database table name

Comment: Does the "Google" contains "Goo"? Yes it does ;)
You can play with words definitions in your $bad_arrays, for example adding a space in the end (so "ALTER " instead of "ALTER" etc...